# RestKit Beginners Guide

Tags: ios, restkit

I am trying to incorporate RestKit into my iOS app but I have been unable to locate a beginner's guide to this API. I tried to follow the GitHub examples but they are not working for me.

Comment: What happens when you use the examples?

Comment: I am following the example from http://liebke.github.com/restkit-github-client-example/ and I get an error where RKObjectManager does not contain a mapper member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object Mapping is one of the prime reasons to use RestKit, you can read about it at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md

An awful lot of the tutorials on the web refer to the older architecture, this document covers the latest stable build.